# startup screen sometimes showing when resuming - does this indicate a potential memory issue with my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone application I'm testing - I've just noted when testing it on a device that sometimes when I resume it (i.e. launch it again in the "multitasking" sense when I expect it to appear and continue on) the startup image appears.  As if it totally restarted.

Would this be an indication of memory issue with the app?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I've noticed this as well and wondered also. It might not be this app that has an issue though, but other apps have required extra memory which caused the system to take memory from this app. Im not sure exactly because (if I recall correctly) the resumed app restarts on the screens it was on, so it didnt lose state. I wonder if in this case, iOS has unloaded some of the backgrounded task's code and its taking a bit of time to read the code back in, so it puts that screen up. However, if this was the case, then the app would really need to be idle and not active in the background.